# anylogic - agent does't leave the queue to enter the restricted area start, which is avaible

Tags: queue, anylogic, agent

I have a queue with maximum capacity. After that I have a restricted area start (capacity=3) to access to the resources (3 bankers). I put a select output to choose the right banker: the client goes to the banker who is avaible. This is the code in the selected output: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Doegk.png)
After that the client receives his service and leave the restrited area. That are the blocks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMG4R.png).

The idea is that the client waits in the queue his turn. When one of the bankers is avaible (known thanks to the restricted area start), the client goes to him. He choses the right banker thanks to the condiction in the select output.
This logic works in the model but not for all the agents. There are some Clients that stay in the queue, even if the restricted area start is not full.
This is an exemple:  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpLC0.png)

the agent leaves the queue only when a new agent arrives in the same queue. This is strange because it happens only sometimes. But all the agent are created in the same way
How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

first, if you already know how to do custom blocks and you have 3 processes that are exactly the same, why not using custom blocks for them?

second, the selectoutput block condition is checked when the agent gets to the queue, and never changes afterwards, it's not automatically recalculated when something happens somewhere else in the model. This happens opposite to what you think

- step 1: agent gets to the queue
- step 2: outputblock condition is
  calculated
- step 3: agent will take THAT path when it's possible to
  take it

It's not that things happen when an agent gets to the queue, actually, when an agent gets to the queue and you see that someone from the queue took one of the paths, it was the same agent that arrived, the other ones inside the queue are still waiting for the path previously calculated to be free.

The right way to model this, is to seize the doctor where you have your queue block and have only one flow instead of 3, and remove the restricted access thing.